# Set a timeout on a tNetezzaInput in Talend

Tags: sql, talend, netezza

I'm making an ETL using Talend, which should permit to create an Excel file with some informations resulting from a tNetezzaInput component in Talend, executing a dynamic query.
It works perfectly. However, some queries finish after 2 hours, depending of the table size ( I have more than 1000 queries to execute ).

I would like to set a timeout (30seconds/1 minute) on my tNetezzaInput.
Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Talend/tNetezzaInput. But you can address this issue at Netezza side using query timeout limits along with runaway query event.

Secondly, how big tables are that query taking 2 hours. Hope its not some query/join issue.

Thanks,
Sanjit

Comment: Hi Sanjit, we have a read-only access to the Netezza database, we can't change setting on this side.
About the tables, some are pretty empty, others have more than 200 millions lines with 100+ columns...

Answer (score 0):

A query on 200 millions records with 100+ columns tables should not take 2 hrs, unless there is some issue with data distribution, join, statistics or workload manager.

Have you checked the pg, dbos logs, planfile about this query?

Thanks,
Sanjit